# How to make studio content changes locally in Sanity

Tags: next.js, content-management-system, sanity

Currently, I have a Next.js site that is using Sanity. If I'm in my local environment and make changes to some content in my Sanity Studio (localhost:3000/studio), the content I add gets added to my live site and the live Sanity Studio. How can I make content changes or implement new content without it being published to the live site?

I tried adding a staging dataset, but when I tried connecting it, my changes were still being pushed to the live site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why your staging is pushing to live, that feels unrelated, but the best way to separate the two is to use environment variables.

So locally and on our staging site in our `.env` file we have:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET="staging"
```

And on our live site on Vercel we have

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET="production"
```

Then make sure your Sanity client dataset is `dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET`

That should be enough.